# How do I use a variable inside of a command block?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm working on a whois slash command for a Discord Bot and I want to display the tag for the user selected within a command block but if I use " or ' for the value of the field on the embed, the variable doesn't work therefore I have to use `. The issue with this is, I can't see a way to show the text outputted by the variable as a code block.

**My code:**

```
            .addFields(
                { name: '__User Information__', value: `**Name:** ${user.tag}\n <:Spacer:1064084066997129277> • Mention: ${user}`, inline:false},
            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape a backtick like so: \`,

So, if you want to add codeblocks inside your embed you can do:

```
`Example codeblock: \`\`\`This is a codeblock! ${variable}\`\`\``
```

Here's an example from my bot, which displays the user id and message id inside a codeblock:

```
`\`\`\`ini\nUser = ${message.member.id}\nID = ${message.id}\`\`\``
```

The code above roughly translates to:

````
```ini
User = ${message.member.id}
ID = ${message.id}
```
````

You can read more about template literals [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)